# Does the Webpack Vivado 2020.2 include the SDK

Tags: sdk, hdl, vivado, petalinux

I am confused. Does Vivado 2021.2 include the SDK using the Webpack license?

Digilent says yes: https://reference.digilentinc.com/programmable-logic/guides/vivado-create-hdl-wrapper

(the hdl wraper is part of the SDK, peta linux, etc)

But, my installation does not seem to include it.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Err... Turns out that Vivado went from SDK to Vitis. So now they are using Vitis for their higher level languages.

https://forum.digilentinc.com/topic/21686-does-anybody-have-the-xilinx-vivado-20194-sdk-xilinx-doesnt-have-in-the-archive/?tab=comments#comment-62563

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Vitis-Acceleration-SDAccel-SDSoC/Vitis-Community-How-can-we-help/td-p/1117972

Here are some examples:

https://reference.digilentinc.com/programmable-logic/guides/getting-started-with-ipi

https://github.com/Xilinx/HLS-Tiny-Tutorials